# Why was it okay for Chief to blow up the warehouse in Wonder Woman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

Near the end of *Wonder Woman*, Steve flies the plane into the air to save everybody from the poison gas. However, Chief puts bombs in the warehouse where the gas was stored and the warehouse blows up. Was that not harmful to people in a 50 mile range like it would be if it was in the plane? How is it different?

Answer (score 5):

Steve asks Chief

> "Is it flammable, Chief?"

and Chief answers in the affirmative.

> "Yeah, she said it's hydrogen. It's flammable"

[image]

So they BURN it when they blow up the warehouse.

[image]

[image]

Comment: of course, that leaves open the obvious follow-up question: why not just burn the plane, too...

Comment: As I recall, they were *going to* but the bomb was on a timer that could not be stopped and the plane took off early when Ares & Diana fought..

Comment: if you assume all the scenes happened in "real time", they actually blew up the warehouse _before_ Steve took off in the plane, so seems like they had time. Maybe there just wasn't a whole lot of gas left in the warehouse when it blew compared to the massive amount loaded on the plane.

Comment: Did they have any good reason to think that the fire would consume all the poison before the explosion could fling it out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the whole output of the poison manufacture was on the plane, while the warehouse only contained the raw materials and the machinery to build more.  So the factory could be safely blown up without danger, while the plane full of poison needed to be destroyed at a great distance.